# How to remove overflow: hidden using with telerik

Tags: c#, telerik

Below is code before convert to `HTML`.I want to change `overflow hidden`.I found many way of `CSS` file. But couldn't find it and try using id to change `css` always no responding.

Telerik Code

```
<telerik:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server" Height="800px" 
 Width="100%"></telerik:ReportViewer>
```

HTML View Through Browser Developer tools

```
<td id="TD_2"> 
    <div id="TD2" style="overflow-y: auto; padding-left: 100px; width: auto; overflow-x: 
     hidden; position: inherit; height: 355px;">
         <telerik:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server" Height="800px" 
          Width="100%"></telerik:ReportViewer>
</td>
```

Comment: Is this what you mean i updated your code.... 
In your telerik look as per that but in browser developer mode you will see as per above ?

Comment: mean that in browser only can view this<td id="TD_2"> <div id="TD2" style="overflow-y: auto; padding-left: 100px; width: auto; overflow-x: hidden; position: inherit; height: 355px;">  </div> </td>